# Characterization of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be an uncountable set, let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the collection of all sets $E\subset X$ such that either $E$ or $E^c$ is at most countable, and define $\mu(E) = 0$ in the first case, $\mu(E) = 1$ in the second. Prove that $\mathfrak{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ and that $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathfrak{M}$. Describe the corresponding measurable functions and
their integrals.

I showed that $\mathfrak{M}$ is $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is a masure on $\mathfrak{M}$. But I have some problems with description of measurable functions.

Here's my thought: Let's consider measurable functions $f:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$. If function $f$ is measurable then $f^{-1}(\{a\})\in \mathfrak{M}$ for any $a\in [-\infty,+\infty]$. Hence either $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ or $(f^{-1}(\{a\}))^c$ is at most countable.

What's next? I would be very thankful is somebody show to me a detailed proof of this. I thought on this problem about 1.5 day but no results.

Comment: I doubt that you need a detailed proof to be provided for you. A gentle push in the right direction should suffice... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is measurable. Let $L_\alpha = f^{-1} ([-\infty, \alpha])$. Note that if $ \alpha \le \beta$ then
$L_\alpha \subset L_\beta$. Also note that either $L_\alpha$ or its complement is countable.

Note that $L_\infty=X$.

Let $m = \inf \{ t |L_t^c \text{ is countable } \}$.
Note that $\mu L_t = 1$ for all $t > m$, and since $\mu X = 1$ we see that
$\mu L_m = \lim_n \mu L_{m+{1 \over n}} = 1$. In particular, $L_m$ is
uncountable.

If $t<m$ then $L_t$ is countable and $\mu L_t = 0$. Since
$\mu L_m = 1$, and $[-\infty,m] = [-\infty,m) \cup \{m\}$ we see that
$\mu \{ x | f(x) = m \} = 1$ or, equivalently, $\mu \{ x | f(x) \ne m \} = 0$.

We see that the measurable functions are those that are constant except at a (at most) countable number of points.

It should be clear that if $m $ is finite, then $\int m d \mu = m$ and
hence $\int f d \mu = m$.

We also see that a measurable $f$ is integrable **iff** $m$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks for answer but may I ask you one question: Why $L_m^c$ is countable? I tried to prove it but no results.

Comment: @RFZ $L_m^c=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (L_{m+\frac{1}{n}})^c $ and for each $n$, $(L_{m+\frac{1}{n}})^c$ is countable.

Comment: Note that I made a mistake in my answer above and in a previously deleted comment.  Will fix shortly.

Comment: (My previous reasoning for why $L_m$ is uncountable was incorrect and has been fixed. It follows from continuity of measure.)

Comment: @copper.hat, Why do you think that your approach was incorrect? I checked it out on paper and I guess that OK. Here's my attempt:

It's easy to see that $L_m=\bigcap \limits _{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$ and hence $L_m^c=\bigcup \limits _{n\in \mathbb{N}}L^c_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$. We have to show that for each $n$ $L^c_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$ is countable. Since $m=\inf\{t: L_t^c \quad\text{is countable}\}$ and by definition of $\inf$ for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ exists $t$ such that $t\in [m,m+\frac{1}{n}]$ such that $L_t^c$ is countable.

Comment: @copper.hat, Then $L_t\subset L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$ and $L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}^c\subset L_t^c$ $\Rightarrow$ $L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}^c$ is countable. Am I right?

Comment: @copper.hat, Also let's prove that $L_m=\bigcap \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$ holds. Suppose $x\in L_m$ then $f(x)\leqslant m$ hence $f(x)\leqslant m+\frac{1}{n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $x\in \bigcap \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$. So $L_m\subset \bigcap \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$.


Let $x\in \bigcap \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$ then $f(x)\leqslant m+\frac{1}{n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $f(x)\leqslant m$ and $x\in L_m$. So $\bigcap \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}\subset L_m$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Finally we get that $L_m=\bigcap \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{m+\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: @RFZ: You are correct. I made a mistake when I thought I had made a mistake :-).

Comment: @copper.hat, What about if $m=-\infty$? If I'm not mistaken then $L_{-\infty}=\bigcap \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{-n}$ then $L_{-\infty}^c=\bigcup \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}L_{-n}^c$ and by analogous reasoning (as above) each $L_{-n}^c$ is countable. Hence $L_{-\infty}^c$ is countable and $L_{-\infty}\in \mathfrak{M}$. Hence $\mu(L_{-\infty})=1$. So $\mu\{x:f(x)=-\infty\}=1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu\{x:f(x)\neq-\infty\}=0$.

The case $m=+\infty$ is obvious since $L_{\infty}^c=X^c=\varnothing$ is finite $\Rightarrow$ countable. Am I right?

Comment: @copper.hat, One more question. Suppose that $m=+\infty$ and $\mu\{x:f(x)=+\infty\}=1$. Let $E=\{x:f(x)=+\infty\}$. So let's a look at integral: $\int \limits_{X}fd\mu=\int \limits_{E}fd\mu+\int \limits_{X-E}fd\mu$ but the second integral is zero since $\mu(X-E)=0$. But we can say about $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu$. Note that $\mu(E)=1$ and $f=+\infty$ on $E$. Is this integral equal to $+\infty$?

Comment: @copper.hat, Let $f=+\infty$ on $E\subset X$ with $\mu(E)=1$. I am going to show that $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=+\infty$.
Since $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=\sup \limits_{0\leqslant s\leqslant f} \int \limits_{E}sd\mu\geqslant \sup \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\int \limits_{E}s_nd\mu$ where $s_n(x)=n$ simple function on $E$. But $\int \limits_{E}s_nd\mu=n.$ And we get that $\sup \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\int \limits_{E}s_nd\mu=+\infty$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=+\infty$.

Comment: @RFZ: (i) If $m=+\infty$ then $L_t$ is countable for all $t < \infty$ hence $L_\infty$ is uncountable (but not necessarily $X$). (ii) When we say that $f$ is integrable we mean $\inf |f| d\mu < \infty$. Hence if $m=\pm \infty$ we see that $f$ is not integrable (although we often write $\inf f d \mu = \pm \infty$ as the case may be). It is measurable.

Comment: @copper.hat, (i)  Note that if $m=+\infty$ then $L_{\infty}=X$ as you wrote. And it's true! Hence $L_{\infty}^c=\varnothing$. (ii) What means notion $\inf |f|d\mu$?

Comment: In my previous comment, $\inf$ should be $\int$. You are correct about $m=+\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat, The best solution! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that every measurable function in this setting is $\mu$-almost surely constant, i.e. if $f \colon X \to [- \infty, \infty]$ is $\mathfrak M$-measurable, then there is a unique constant $c \in [- \infty, \infty]$ such that $\mu ( \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = c \}) = 1$.

Once you've verified this, the part regarding integrals is trivial: $\int f d \mu = c$, where $c$ is the unique constant from above.

Comment: Actually you gave me an answer to question. But can you give me advice\hint how to get this?

Comment: @RFZ Let $a,b$ distinct elements in the range of $f$. Then $f^{-1}(\{a\}) \cap f^{-1}(\{b\}) = \emptyset$, but at most one of $f^{-1}(\{a\}), f^{-1}(\{b\})$ can be uncountable. If $c$ is the unique member of the range of $f$ such that $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ is uncountable, then the above proves $\mu(\{ x \in X \mid f(x) = c \}) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for hint. I spent some time to realize what did you mean. Indeed, if $a$ and $b$ are distinct elements from $[-\infty,+\infty]$ then $f^{-1}(\{a\})\cap f^{-1}(\{b\})=\varnothing$ (if they have common element then we get contradiction with $a\neq b$). Also as you said at most one of the $f^{-1}(\{a\}), f^{-1}(\{b\})$ can be uncountable. If at least they both are uncountable then $f^{-1}(\{a\})\subset (f^{-1}(\{b\}))^c$ which is also contradiction because we get that uncountable set is the subset of countable set.

Comment: Also it's easy to see that $$X=\bigsqcup\limits _{a\in [-\infty,+\infty]}f^{-1}(\{a\}).$$ So we have two cases: 1) If $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is countable for any $a\in [-\infty,+\infty]$ I guess that we have some contradiction which I can't realize. Can you help please with this?

Comment: I am still thinking about case when $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is countable for any $a\in [-\infty,+\infty]$. How to get contradiction but no results :(

Comment: Did you delete your last comment?

Comment: Yes, I did. The reason is, that it was a teaser that I anticipated to result in additional questions (which I attended it to do), but something else came up and thus I don't have time right now to assist you on that. Sorry. In case you or someone else don't answer your question, I intend to do it myself, as soon as I cleared my agenda.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand you. Are you claiming that you can't help me with problem right?

Comment: I'm not able to help you *right now*. I'll come back to you later (, unless someone else already helped you out.)

Comment: OK. I'll be waiting for you.